# i need to replace only the last occurrence of anything in parenthesis using preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace all the occurrence of anything in parenthesis at the end of the string with nothing. But i dont want same to happen to anything that is inside the string.  For example if i have a string  "Special (NOT) Value (SV)" then the preg_replace should only replace the end parenthesis so the result should be "Special (NOT) Value"

Comment: As usual: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have pattern "(\(.*?\))" which will find all the occurrence, but i just want to find the one that occurs at the end

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed using the explode function? You can define the pattern, and you can concatenate the arrays afterwards...   http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

the dollar character match end of string. The regex below should do what you want, except if you can have parenthesis inside parenthesis, in wich case you should define more precisely what you'are expecting to get an answer. (Now I'll leave you understand what's going on and what is wrong with your first tries)

```
<?
$str = 'Special (NOT) Value (SV)';
$str = preg_replace('/[(][^)]*[)]([^(]*$)/', '$2', $str);
echo $str."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php), you'll see that you can use the `$` character to assert the end of a line.  So `blah.*?$` will find the last occurrence of `blah` in a string.

That's not the complete answer, but should be enough to get you going.

Comment: No, in `blahxyzblah` it will also match the first one, because the string `xyzblah` match against `.*`.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Not with the `?` modifier.